# Laravel query works halfway

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query

```
$categories = Category::with('products')
            ->OfListed() // this is my scope has nothing to do with my issues.
            ->orderby('id', 'desc')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
```

It works half way! meaning:

> **I get my categories with their products**, but *I don't get them in order by
>   id*, **also** *I get them all instead of only last 10 of them*.

how I show them in blade:

```
@foreach($categories as $kis)
  @foreach($kis->products as $ki)
    {{$ki->title}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

any idea?

Comment: Try to replace `get()` => `toSql()` and  dump it to check sql query

Comment: Do you mean "products" instead of "posts"?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir no i ment `products`

Comment: "I get my categories with their posts"

Comment: @iwex this is what i get `"select * from `categories` where `listed` = ? order by `id` desc limit 10"`

Comment: @mafortis so it's correct query. Maybe you have issue with your scope?

Comment: Do you want 10 categories or 10 products?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I want to get 10 products of that category which has listed (my scope)

Comment: @mafortis now you're querying 10 last categories, not products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this if you want 10 products and ordered

```
$categories = Category::with([
   'products' => function($query){
       $query->orderby('id', 'desc');
    }
 ])->OfListed()->get();
```

And in blade

```
@foreach($categories as $kis)
  @foreach($kis->products->take(10) as $ki)
    {{$ki->title}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Edited answer as O.P. said it worked
Check this in the docs, https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads

Comment: it broke my othe categories results, now my other listed categories which have less that 10 products in it are not showing https://ibb.co/mwrY7n

Comment: That is... odd, try to do the same thing you did before, `get() => toSql()`

Comment: "select * from `categories` where `listed` = ?"

Comment: Try to put `dd($categories)`; after you get them ( with get() )

Comment: `take(10)` doesn't work here. It selects 10 products for all categories combined.

Comment: yes i add it in my blade and now it's working just fine. you might want edit your answer before i accept it.

Comment: now i have your query minus `take(10)` and this in my blade `@foreach($kis->products->take(10) as $ki)` working 100%

Comment: Edited answers as you said it worked, still think is weird the take(10) didn't work while querying.

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
@foreach($categories as $i => $kis)
  <div>Category {{{ $i }}}</div>
  @foreach($kis->products as $ki)
    {{$ki->title}}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

you will see that you are getting only 10 categories. Since your loop was only displaying the titles of the products, you couldn't see how many categories you were getting. Take a look at your method for retrieving products - it is probably selecting more than intended.